# "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" breaks css 3d perspective

Tags: html, ios, css, overflow, mobile-safari

> Searching for a solution for **iOS safari ONLY**

When using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` it breaks the 3d perspective on iOS.

See the demo on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/abernier/pen/qdaxro).

**HTML**

```
<div class="pers">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="el">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pers {perspective:300px;}
.scroll {overflow-y:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; height:100vh;}
.el {-webkit-transform:rotateX(80deg);transform:rotateX(80deg);}
```

[image]
[image]

Is there a workaround?

Comment: That is a weird bug, and unfortunately the `transform: translateZ(0);` hack that works for some other `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` bugs doesn't seem to help. BTW, I think your codepen might be missing some code, as removing `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` doesn't make it work either. Here's a codepen that showed the issue for me:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJNoNW

Comment: Does anybody knows if implementing a native `overflow` WITH MOMENTUM is on Apple's roadmap (without all that `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` mess) ? Any link appreciated.

Comment: Inertial scrolling is not a part of any spec that I know of, so it probably won't be unprefixed.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with overflow and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`. Remove overflow and perspective is correct but the overflow is not handled correctly.

Comment: @AndrewLi just tested removing the `overflow-y:scroll;` from `.scroll`: it does NOT correct the perspective which is still flat... tested on that forked version http://codepen.io/abernier/pen/RKRoOY on an iPad

Comment: @abernier That's weird. For me, it's perspective is correct but it doesn't move. It's stuck in one perspective on my screen in the codepen you forked.

Comment: @AndrewLi yes my bad you are correct : http://i.imgur.com/7yEgJSm.png

Comment: I'm afraid there is no plausible solution to this.

Answer (score 9):

**Update, May 29**

Doh! I so stupid. The below, while true...ish doesn't address the question well enough.

If you want that configuration of the rotation to stay the same as you have illustrated, add a div between `.scroll` and `.el`, and style it such:

```
{perspective:300px;}
```

Thus, it would seem that you want the `.pers` div switched with `.scroll` or add another after `.scroll` with the same perspective.

Also, try moving the `perspective: 300px;` to `.scroll`. The angle appears to change as one scroll up or down.

---

**Original Answer**

The answer is not really. One cannot contain a 3D transform inside a container with clipping which is being attempted here.

The problem is `overflow-y:scroll` breaks the transform-style property as per [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transforms-20120911/#transform-style). The overflow-y affects the nested element. If your problem persists, you may also have to use the `-WebKit-transform-style: preserve-3d` declaration on `.scroll`, though I think iOS already has a stacking context established in this case (Firefox requires this, Webkit seems not to).

One solution is to remove your `overflow:hidden` from `body` and `overflow-y:scroll` from `.scroll`, but I suspect you are going to want to have that as a smaller part of the page/screen and move image blocks inside it.

If this is the case, you will need fake this with transforms and some clever hackery and should use opacity be part of this endeavor, please note that this too (as in spec above, right below the transform-style) causes the flattening effect when not applied to the final node. Let's say you had opacity other than 1 on `.el`, you are fine here as `.el` is the final node, but if opacity was applied to `.scroll`, the same flattening of `.el` occurs as with the overflow.

Have yet to test on iOS as I lack access to the device.

Note: setting an overflow value other than visible for the body does not cause this issue on most desktop browsers that support 3D transforms. I do not know about iOS/mobile.

Comment: Can you provide live demos links ? Maybe the question isn't very clear but it is about iOS Safari mobile only. It works great on other browsers. So I'm just looking for a solution to it.

Comment: I will try it out in the later today when I have access to my friend's iPhone. There is no doubt that the scrolling touch hack is interfering with the 3D. There is the distinct possibility that it cannot be fixed as iOS webkit has some funny interpretations of 3D transforms where the desktop Safari and Chrome display correctly. Do you need iPad also, or only phone?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the question. Thx for participating anyway ;)

Comment: can you provide a codepen of your last answer to clarify ? thx ;)

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but you seem to have a solution but unfortunately I can't really understand your explainations. Can you just provide a codepen in order I could validate your solution ? thx ;)

Comment: if anyone who has voted up has a working demo link of @thisiate's solution (on codepen or whatever), it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the bug that didn't fixed from apple yet.
only way to solve this problem is put container with Higher height and perspective around element then make upper container to scroll it.

```
<div class="pers">
  <div class="scroll">
     <div class="widerHeight">
       <div class="el">
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

```
.pers {/*perspective:300px;*/}
.scroll {overflow-y:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;height:100vh }
.widerWidth {min-height:1000px;perspective:300px;}
.el {-webkit-transform:rotateX(80deg);transform:rotateX(80deg);}
```

Answer (score -1):

The shared snippet does not work on Mozilla Firefox as well. Below is the **solution tested for iOS Safari/Chrome (iPhone-6S), Windows Mozilla/Chrome:**

**no need to use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`.** There could be a possible bug for this feature as it is under development  [[Reference Link]](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-overflow-scrolling). Removing this property generates the desired behavior. It might not be the exact solution, but it can act as a workaround.

```
.scroll {perspective:300px;overflow-y:scroll;height:100vh;}
.el {-webkit-transform:rotateX(80deg);transform:rotateX(80deg);}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxZZdX

Comment: You're right -- and of course :) -- not using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` solves the issue BUT there is no more momentum scrolling which was exactly what I was looking for using that property :))

Answer (score -1):

This snippet from [HERE](http://patrickmuff.ch/blog/2014/10/01/how-we-fixed-the-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-bug-on-ios/)   might do it. They seem to have had this issue as well

```
.outer {`enter code here`
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /* More properties for a fixed height ... */
}

.inner {
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
}
```

Comment: can you fork the original codepen and apply your solution to it? I fear the issue it adresses isn't related with the 3d one...

Answer (score -3):

Please check this demo: http://codepen.io/tushar-chauhan/pen/yNgzem
You can try tweaking the values to get your desired results. This works on both mobile & desktop Safari. I am posting the HTML & CSS here too:

#### CSS & HTML below:

```css
body{
  width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
}
.pers{
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  height: 120vh;
  margin: 0 auto; overflow-y: auto;
}
.scroll {
  height: inherit;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
.el {
  width: 10em; height: 10em; background: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);background-size:cover;
  margin: 80vh auto;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 35%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(80deg);
  transform: rotateX(80deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="pers">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="el">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does retain the 3d-perspective on scroll. I tried to make some changes with respect to momentum scrolling, but it seems like mobile safari behaves in a different way while scrolling with 3d perspective on.