# Overflow breaking CSS Perspective on Android 4.4

Tags: css, android-4.4-kitkat, css-transforms

I am working on a parallax background for a mobile web app, and it is breaking on Android 4.4. It works on desktop, Android 5+, and iOS 9, but on Android 4.4, perspective is not having any effect when `overflow` is `auto` or `scroll`. Setting it to `visible` will fix the perspective effect, but breaks the parallax effect, because the parent is doing the scrolling, not the perspective element.

See http://codepen.io/MalikDrako/pen/WwoKBJ/left for an example. (the content works best at a mobile width, ex: 320px)

How can i keep the scrolling with the parallax effect?

Edit: I think my 4.4 test device overheated and shut down. When I turned it back on and turned on GPU profiling, I discovered it is constantly drawing even though nothing changed. Is there any way to make it redraw (mostly) only when something changes?

Comment: Instead of setting overflow directly on the parallax element, add a div of 100% height inside it, set its overflow and put content inside it

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, that breaks on desktop as well, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30427085/1269846